# Pass textbox value to controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

how can i pass the value from textbox to controller class file ?

```
 for(int i =0 ; i< 5 ; i ++)
{
 <div>
      <input class="form-control" name="@("test"+i)" value="">
 </div>
}
```

### testController.cs

```
 public ActionResult Create(String[] test)
 {
       //???
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to pass all the values from input type ?

Comment: yes... all the value from textbox

Comment: Just `name="test"` - that is what the name of your parameter is (have you not read any of the links I gave in your previous question?)

Comment: Every time you have 5 inputs ?

Comment: Using `name` HTML attribute is simply doing POST with `Bind` (and `Include`) set in controller method argument.

Comment: You need to place the razor code inside a form and add a submit button which post to the right controller's method. Then, the mvc infrastructure does all the job.

Comment: Note that you should use same name for all text input (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616052/binding-arrays-in-asp-net-mvc-without-index). As an alternative, use a viewmodel containing `IEnumerable` with indexed `TextBoxFor` (e.g. `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].Test)`) inside loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all your textboxes inside a form , so that they get posted when you hit form submit.

And if you need to push all the values as an array then you need to name your text boxes as an array. Just like

```
<input type="text" name="test[0]" id="test_0"/>
<input type="text" name="test[1]" id="test_1"/>
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to Stephen ans Tetsuya's comments below, It also seems it is already answered in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616052/binding-arrays-in-asp-net-mvc-without-index).

So, if you want to receive a plain string array in your controller, you simply need to name all your text boxes with the same name. i.e. name="test"

Comment: You do not need the indexers when its an array of a simple type - all that needed is `name="test"`

Comment: It already explained here: [Binding arrays in ASP.NET MVC without index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616052/binding-arrays-in-asp-net-mvc-without-index).

Comment: @StephenMuecke My Bad! I never tried that with simple type. I've updated my answer now

Answer (score 0):

```
 @for(int i =0 ; i< 5 ; i ++)
{
 <div>
      <input class="form-control" name="test" value="">
 </div>
}
```

and the controller;

```
public ActionResult Create(List<string> test)
 {

 }
```

it will automatically pass the values as a `List<>`. After than you can extract it with `foreach` in the controller

Answer (score 0):

You should use Html.BeginForm In code side you can access by representation method as Post method. You must add [POST] tag on top of method and write parameter that is if you want.